# Unable to compare date & time with current time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I am using [bootstrap date time picker library](http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/demo.php) and getting value from document like this.

```
var accountExpiry = jQuery(".tempExpiry input").val();
```

> returns = "12 October 2015 - 03:35 PM"

and my goal is to compare accountExpiry time with `Date.now()` and alert user Expiry must greater than current time.

I have tried following jquery but that is wrong:

```
var accountExpiry = jQuery(".tempExpiry input").val();
if (accountExpiry > Date.now()) { 
    console.log("OK");
} else { 
    console.log("Select time must be greater than current"); 
}
```

Comment: to make it work you have to parse the string to a Date object ..

Comment: You need to parse the string to a Date object. However this will not be simple as that format will not be automatically recognised. You either need to change the string format, or write your own parser. I would *strongly* recommend the former.

Comment: .tempExpiry input - this is jquery datepicker ?

Comment: try this `var accountExpiry = new Date(jQuery("input").val().replace('-',''));`

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1e810rzp/)

```
var accountExpiry = "12 October 2015 - 08:35 AM"; //change this with jQuery(".tempExpiry input").val()
var date = new Date(Date.parse(accountExpiry.replace(" -",""))) ;
if (date > new Date(Date.now())) { 
    console.log(date , new Date(Date.now()) ,"less");
} else { 
    console.log(date , new Date(Date.now()) ,"greater"); 
}
```